# No audio on simultaneous webrtc p2p connections

Tags: webrtc

I've created a webrtc p2p app using socket io for signalling.
This work perfectly with one connection pair. When there are more than one connection pair, the video works well but the audio isn't hear on the other side.

I've deployed TURN server, it works as intended.

I'm not able to isolate the issue as in where does this issue lie. 
I've been searching on google with no luck. It's been 3 days now

It would be great if anyone would point me to a right direction

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Comment: I understand that, I'm not asking for writing my code. I'm asking for possible issues